# Two separate angularJS apps on the same file system

Tags: angularjs, routes, directory-structure

My routes will look something like this:

```
/create-company/index.html#/part-one
/dashboard/index.html#/view1
/auth/
```

Now the `create-company` app is used initially and from then on the branch `dashboard` app is used.

Currently I use the seed project to make `app, config, logs, scripts & test folders` in my home directory for one app.

To add the second app, Should I create two folders `app1 & app2` which each contain their own `app, config, logs, scripts & test folders`?

Then I can point `/dashboard/` to `/app1/app` and point `/create-company/` to `/app2/app`

Or would it be better to stick with a single angularJS app at `/app/` and to point both `/create-company/` and `/dashboard/` to the same `/app/` folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there may be use-cases where having multiple, completely separated apps is helpful and/or appropriate, from your description the two 'apps' you describe would appear to be different sub-sections of one larger app.

Consider in your usage, would there be any overlapping components, such as shared directives, templates, or services? If so, it would be best to avoid duplication.

In addition, there is no restriction on loading the same app on two different pages, with different markup - controllers etc, which would lead to completely different functionality.

For example the following is perfectly fine on different pages:

```
<body>
    <div ng-app="my-app">
        <div ng-controller="createCompany">
            <!-- Section specific content here, directives etc -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<body>
    <div ng-app="my-app">
        <div ng-controller="dashboard">
            <!-- Section specific content here, directives etc -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you explain how the last paragraph works.
Looks like i'll use the one app then. Do I just create index1.html and index2.html? (i'm fairly new to angular)

Comment: Yes - that's right. You can load the same app and dependencies on both pages (all the same JS), but then use different HTML markup on the page, to load the content you would like. I'll add an example.

Comment: Cheers. It's just my current index.html has dashboard specific stuff for view1, view2, view3 etc. So putting create-company view inside index.html wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: Sure, and that is a problem our company has come across too. The issue was whether to combine and load the 'entire' app on one page (so it is cached and primed for subsequent loads), or whether to break up modules and load only those required for the page. We ended up combining and minifying, but your use may differ.

Comment: Lets say the "different pages" you mention are index1.html and index2.html,
Lets say both have a route with the same name e.g. /dashboard/index1.html#start & /create-company/index2.html#start
How would that look in the apps $routeProvider config?

Comment: Do they need to be the same? If you follow deep-linking routes strictly, you would just have one page, for example `app.html`, which would have routes like `#dashboard`, `#create-company`, `#create-company-step-two`. If you want to break up the pages, do you really need to have two routes named `start` in your app?

Comment: It seems unlikely that there will be conflict.
I would have used .com/#create-company & .com/#dashboard, But because the app is in a "static directory" on google app engine, that means I wouldn't be able to do authorization. Hence I have the /auth/* which goes to python scripts.

Comment: Unless it's possible for me to have all urls after / go to the /app/ static directory but put an exception in for /auth/ which I can probably do with app.yaml but that's another story